# Import column from multiple csv to a new csv powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

Hi I am a novice and struggling really bad on powershell.

I have 5 csv files which all have 1 column. I want to take the column from each csv file and put them into a new csv file and have each column taken from the 5 csv files as a separate column in the new csv

outcome to be this

```
temp1 | temp2 | temp3 | temp4 | temp5|
```

can someone please help me with this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: presuming they all have the same number of rows ... load the files into independent $Vars, iterate thru one of them, build a `PSCustomObject` that has a prop from each $Var, then export that to a CSV file.

Comment: Do any of these input CSV files (or all of them) have a header, or are they just lists of values each on a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It is comma-delimited data. I could not tell if you wanted pipe-delimited based on your question or if that was for demonstration purposes. I also could not tell if the temp nomenclature was the new value of the columns you wanted or if that was already the name of each column in each file. It  assumes there are no commas in your data.

```
$CSV1 = Get-Content csv1.csv
$CSV2 = Get-Content csv2.csv
$CSV3 = Get-Content csv3.csv
$CSV4 = Get-Content csv4.csv
$CSV5 = Get-Content csv5.csv
$MostRows = ($CSV1.count,$CSV2.count,$CSV3.count,$CSV4.count,$CSV5.count | Sort-Object -Descending)[0]

$Output = For ($i = 0; $i -lt $MostRows; $i++) {
    $CSV1[$i],$CSV2[$i],$CSV3[$i],$CSV4[$i],$CSV5[$i] -Join ","
}

$Output | Set-Content NewCSV.csv
```

Here is an alternative that uses objects and protects commas in data. This uses your temp nomenclature for the column names. This can be manually adjusted to whatever you like by updating the names in the hashtable.

```
$CSV1 = Get-Content csv1.csv
$CSV2 = Get-Content csv2.csv
$CSV3 = Get-Content csv3.csv
$CSV4 = Get-Content csv4.csv
$CSV5 = Get-Content csv5.csv
$MostRows = ($CSV1.count,$CSV2.count,$CSV3.count,$CSV4.count,$CSV5.count | Sort-Object -Descending)[0]

$Output = For ($i = 0; $i -lt $MostRows; $i++) {
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{"temp1"=$CSV1[$i];"temp2"=$CSV2[$i];"temp3"=$CSV3[$i];"temp4"=$CSV4[$i];"temp5"=$CSV5[$i]}
}

$Output | Export-CSV NewCSV.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: This is assuming the input CSV files aren't csv files at all, but lists of values without CSV headers. From the question _without examples_, there is no telling if this is indeed the case.

Comment: @Theo, this is correct. I feel some vital information is missing to compose an ideal solution.